# how to declare class prop on typescript?

Tags: typescript, class

this is from a code in fire base:

```
class Fire { 
 ...
}

Fire.shared = new Fire(); // error on .shared
export default Fire;
```

the error i'm getting is

> 'Property 'shared' does not exist on type 'typeof Fire'

how do i fix this in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You need use the keyword `static` in front of the property name to declare them as [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) just like in a regular javascript

```
class Fire {
  static shared: Fire = new Fire()
  ...
}
```